# Error encode/decode Base64 between Java and Android

Tags: java, android, encryption, base64

I have a problem when I encode/decode Base64 between Java and Android.

Here is my case:

I write code to encrypt/decrypt using ECC on Java, my code work very well.

Then I try to encrypt string on Java and decrypt this encrypted string on Android, it fail.

I think the problem maybe encode/decode Base64.

Here is my code:

Encrypt/decrypt on Java only:

```
  //ENCRYPT
try {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("ECIES",BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,publicKey);
        encodeBytes = c.doFinal(origin.getBytes());

        String encrypt = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encodeBytes);

        System.out.println("Encrypt:"+ encrypt+"\n");


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

//////DECRYPT
    try
    {
        String abc = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encrypt);
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("ECIES","BC");
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,privateKey);
        //decodeBytes = c.doFinal(encodeBytes);
        decodeBytes = c.doFinal(abc);
        String deCrypt = new String(decodeBytes,"UTF-8");

        System.out.println("Decrypt:"+ deCrypt +"\n");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is my result:

```
private key: EC Private Key [eb:bc:b0:30:f0:42:4e:f1:0f:c5:6a:49:22:93:51:72:ea:23:0c:9a]
        X: c55275cd4a40690ec8d5333cd31994e3066d7f49f57df6c3aed20385c6b50325
        Y: b1a2c67c9c3ac8b8508e210cb2ac476999a913b85e283359fd4482d68164c7e9


public key: EC Public Key [eb:bc:b0:30:f0:42:4e:f1:0f:c5:6a:49:22:93:51:72:ea:23:0c:9a]
        X: c55275cd4a40690ec8d5333cd31994e3066d7f49f57df6c3aed20385c6b50325
        Y: b1a2c67c9c3ac8b8508e210cb2ac476999a913b85e283359fd4482d68164c7e9


Encrypt:BG+pFzDgRLhTI44Rj9w3zkTprPqTryOrqP8xfrS7tb5H3e0KGoxyq/e5SngwQeAr91aGBn6jAUNupwqEihYta7epTtpLP84d7LFxgTJs+bsYgu3WskadiLSImjigzLM1g/VgZ2PWk1Y7idAX

Decrypt:63B952562----0907888511
```

Then I write code to decrypt string on Android, but Android not have this method:

```
Base64.getDecoder().decode(String);
```

I must replace it with this:

```
byte[] encodeBytes = null;
encodeBytes = Base64.encode(my_encrypted_string.getBytes(),Base64.DEFAULT);
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("ECIES","SC");
c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,privateKeyFromFile);
decodeBytes = c.doFinal(encodeBytes);
String deCrypt = new String(decodeBytes,"UTF-8");
txtHiden.setText(deCrypt);
Toast.makeText(activity, deCrypt, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

But it shows this error:

```
10-03 09:50:24.466 13134-13134/com.example.napoleon.luanvana W/System.err: org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.util.BadBlockException: unable to process block
```

Comment: It is too difficult to reproduce your problem. Is there any code which can be compiled easily in java and android?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a simple mistake. 
You replaced

```
String abc = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encrypt);
```

with

```
byte[] encodeBytes = null;
encodeBytes = Base64.encode(my_encrypted_string.getBytes(),Base64.DEFAULT);
```

if I read this correctly. Try to replace that with [`decode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html#decode(java.lang.String,%20int)) instead.

As the ciphertext is Base64 encoded twice instead of decoded before attempting to decrypt it, decryption fails with the error you showed us.